# Are Live Bookmarks in Places.sqlite?

Tags: firefox, database, bookmarks, sqlite, rss

In [reading about](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite) `Places.sqlite`, it's not clear to me whether or not that includes [Live Bookmarks](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Live_Bookmarks_-_Firefox).

How can I access, either through sqlite or by other means, the `Live Bookmarks`?  I've installed the [SQLite Manager](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) to take a closer look at this database.

I think that the `moz_places` table has the actual URL's?  From a cursory examination, it seems like `Live Bookmarks` are included, but I don't know for a fact.

Comment: In `moz_bookmarks`, I was able to find my live bookmarks, but not the current contents. (I'm an SQL beginner, so I just ran `sqlite3 <filename> "SELECT * from moz_bookmarks"` and grepped the result for the name of a live bookmark, then the name of a current entry in that bookmark.) As far as I can tell, Firefox stores them as RSS feeds, then populates the contents at runtime. If you're still interested in extracting the results, try adding the feed link as a regular bookmark, then resolving it with a reader/JS/Iframe/etc. The feeds *may* be XML.